# Update static variable from another class

Tags: java, android

I have an activity on my app where a user can update their registered information stored in a remote database. When the update button is pressed the information in the database is being updated but the static variable is not changing. Here is my code thanks in advance for any help!

```
    btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String first_name = First_name.getText().toString();
            final String last_name = Last_name.getText().toString();
            final String email = Email.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            LoginActivity.first_name = jsonResponse.getString("first_name");
                            LoginActivity.last_name = jsonResponse.getString("last_name");
                            LoginActivity.email_address = jsonResponse.getString("email");

                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateInfoActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Submission Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            };

            UpdateInfoRequest updateInfoRequest = new UpdateInfoRequest(first_name, last_name, email, userID, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UpdateInfoActivity.this);
            queue.add(updateInfoRequest);

            Intent intent = new Intent(UpdateInfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            UpdateInfoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't see a static variable.

Comment: @Izruo LoginActivity.first_name... etc

Comment: show your `LoginActivity` class

Comment: Whoever told you to use static variables here was wrong, by the way

Comment: I only have got one idea: A malformed JSON causes the `new JSONObject(String)` constructor to throw a `JSONException`. That exception is just catched and logged, but afterwards the data is just updated as if nothing had happened. Can you please check your log (or to whatever `exc.printStackTrace()` prints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
if (success) {
   LoginActivity.first_name = first_name;
   LoginActivity.last_name = last_name;
   LoginActivity.email_address = email;
}
```

and I wouldn't be using static variables like that if you want to have a global user profile you could do this

```
class User {

        private static User user = null;

        public String firstName = "";

        private User() {}

        public static synchronized User getInstance() {

            if (user == null) user = new User();

            return user;
        }
    }
```

to retrieve data from anywhere in project call this

`String name = User.getInstance().firstName;`

And to modify the data do this

`User.getInstance().firstName = UserName;`

Comment: @NiamLeeson be aware this completely ignores the JSON response

Comment: @cricket_007 how does it ignore JSON response?? the question states that he wants to update his static variables after successfully updating remote server

Comment: This...? `first_name = jsonResponse.getString("first_name");` It no longer exists... Are you assuming that the JSON does not contain that data? With your code, you set the values to those from the `EditText` values, therefore *ignoring the JSON*

Comment: the question states that the data is successfully updated in the database but! not the static variables, why? coz the problem lies from `jsonResponse.getString` doesn't return user details. and where you don't need to return the user details if you already have them from the `EditText`. and also we not ignoring JSON completely coz we have the `success boolean` which we get from the json response... Oh and one thing our job is to find problems in code/remove problems in code or add our own code to solve the problem, I simply removed the problem and now the code works as expected

Answer (score 0):

First Understand that static variables are shared by all objects and methods of the class.

So we only have one instance of the static variable.

The ways to Update static variable from other class -

1.Through object.
2.Through Class name.

Enclosing the code sample.

```
    class A{
      static int val;
      public A(){val=0; }
      //....
    }
  class B{
       A obj= new A();
       public void updateStatic(){
              obj.val=10; // updates values through object to 10
              A.val=100;  //updates values through class name to 100
}
//..
}
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

> but the static variable is not changing.

Should be... You told the code to do that

```
if (success) {
    LoginActivity.first_name = jsonResponse.getString("first_name");
    LoginActivity.last_name = jsonResponse.getString("last_name");
    LoginActivity.email_address = jsonResponse.getString("email");
}
```

Just want to mention...

1) You update a String, not any TextView or EditText in your question, so if you expected to see a "visual change" in your app, then no, nothing will happen unless you call `setText`.

2) That code is wrapped in a try-catch, and could error, so check the logs for a `JSONException`. If those keys aren't sent back from the server, then sure, they won't update. For example, the JSON is only `{"success": true }`

Still, `SharedPrefences` should largely be preferred over `static` variables here.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer of data between activities using the static variable is not a better way in my opinion. It is bad practice. Transferring data using intents or save data in storage media and accessing from there will be the better solution.